# Force direct layout in VEGA with labels

Tags: javascript, frontend, vega

I'm attempting to create a network plot in VEGA using a force-directed layout that displays labels for each node. One possible approach was mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121161/how-to-add-a-text-field-to-a-symbol-mark.). By referring to the [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-EK9AmcwAEXamGt3gGWp1qANjOZrJA7M56G5GttAvFIpdQqdEClnrxrwR2YBiTDNPemEUtOjxtj8ctH3gUDMTDY31lePkShUagkpwAysGgtpqcokD1qh5skgkqQavJ3DRPtpC5gKf0ZPnTm4FyXte83HcIHAZD3UM8QHBSOJMA90BBwghm0ZUAgooeophHgBCC9wK+UJjRJgEgQAAurEzjGmwjjPq+cC-Ci-yAug+73CcXo-leN4gHeD5sE+L4UnAtRZAhaKbgu2gAD6UZUFZoXiGHXqcjw4Y+MGEbIUHiOBzJQexh6-CB2gAHxOLx0EEYeL6kJ+pFISAnzhAAFAAlAME6hqg5a0lCIFeh2UDKKo6inAA4nYOCuES1Qvtm2j+N4V5GOE5RXlkU5BCEzj0Gu3oItZO4RuIDBGEYx4aGejFYaxeH8URpCKHJCJbouAC86W0bS2gAPzlEECCqdoqCzmhentgohldiZ6AAGJhCkQH2QowaKFiNWeGUBwICFRYSNovx9YhSCpGqPIQL5G6Js16SWlSpZoChh7hU8oBRbG1y3EY5GtjIvyIclFEAGSHfOnyUL0GwjLpukyENK1+Yqhh3btihbegQ0EPyh7dL042iD2MgTsgdagJg4Q4Ai-2SMsihsBDrXIug1kPG28oIn6Zi+ACKAvW9cjY597TuWOf1iNDIBAwCsZgxDpxQwMOCw-DYOnBjKM3dhUB3Ao92TYieGeAMNMIp46x3AMnHIKmoB3UjSpY8G6k0HARgmiAthRNKMIgEm7ygFwiAIlzQRkJ44TguMUDQhzyCKGYN5nnzyNC+DBb3o+AyHMycCuoDsMILGstnPLd3ayeZ7lrMGqJch24ivoNBuIjwfyIFPOx2lGXadUuXAG4nzFdZlCfLESeF0qlDhFCRXaHnBenY84xge44TFSljyCnpuKg8oZDR6cn4pbaCdJ49mqllhdeFyFYUt9PoVQtCYHnqUSqxr+QQx6AW6hetXO9KcUAC4lgPK6rpwa-B2vZrDZh6yA4YIo4MB0Gh2t7WRprYUc98beL6Dgm0AAKhKqSKwFJgGgLJBSXEiIihiC3g-ea6AcBsFMJva22tyzWggEDe6wtNwdV5K-Ow3ZxA3gNNsfwhZWrrVmJtLk01aHXwHMWL+f88bLmLNfeh-8KZEPUkQh228BEfA3iRGQYp9a8Lxl8WBiNpE3D4Uia2eINJGzwiYVOMg7DgJvIohhcsSTQPZmo0RZxmyyGRJKEoZARjsJkWPVU6o35mK8OjUwZgBhs1Zp4hWOM5BBhDL-RxvpPGBkLKUN+ekyqg1dqcIInxZoU39oHbGY8UYyHQe5ace4DxHhXhgr+O83qgEfqcHoU4vHaw8FeXsP9YzlNQI6NsK8j6py-h-JCoAFEUzPmraxIA2BuDcIeEG38lF42smA8kEBIEGHGJQAAnKohSsYtwqzVjtEAiTxkbPPu9AEDAECUA3NrO49DGnIMROIxKspUY7PiSggEMB1KpK-kHDG-jYHZIyGoUgC18kyF-O0++XTf7ljYHfK5u5TgAGIChWxYbfOAAB1GgwxXlfyaYsgQ9yZDYPIXg08cTaZhPMCsEYOi4AAEcGA0H8HQyZhD3GwIgGqMlIA-S8jEEUbwAANU4iFjmUF5e44uAwxXeAAJpCqOScqVcBK5CxcZgQVhyVwnJahqTAEqCWqtlRqkV2q4C6uRNdPSQA), we can observe that the labels are present, but there are some issues with overlapping and visual clutter.

Consequently, I was wondering if would be possible achieving a result similar to [this example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/global-development/), where the label appears when hovering over a node and remains highlighted and fixed within the chart.

I've tried some changes in 'text' field but I guess it can be more complex than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements aren't completely clear to me. I created this force directed chart with labelling here:

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/packed-bubble-chart/

[image]

Here is a force directed layout I also created with dynamic labelling.

[image]

https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Do either of these help?

Comment: Dear @David Bacci, thank you for your reply. If you go to "Vega Editor" link, you'll see that all labels are shown. However, I would like to plot the same network but with the responsiveness similar to the third link, in which you can put mouse on a node and than the label is shown and can be fixed. Is this explanation more precise?

Answer (score 0):

use this configs:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A node-link diagram with force-directed layout, depicting character co-occurrence in the novel Les Misérables.",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  "padding": 0,
  "autosize": "none",

  "signals": [
    { "name": "cx", "update": "width / 2" },
    { "name": "cy", "update": "height / 2" },
    { "name": "nodeRadius", "value": 8,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 50, "step": 1} },
    { "name": "nodeCharge", "value": -30,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min":-100, "max": 10, "step": 1} },
    { "name": "linkDistance", "value": 30,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 5, "max": 100, "step": 1} },
    { "name": "static", "value": true,
      "bind": {"input": "checkbox"} },
    {
      "description": "State variable for active node fix status.",
      "name": "fix", "value": false,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseout[!event.buttons], window:mouseup",
          "update": "false"
        },
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseover",
          "update": "fix || true"
        },
        {
          "events": "[symbol:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "xy()",
          "force": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Graph node most recently interacted with.",
      "name": "node", "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseover",
          "update": "fix === true ? item() : node"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Flag to restart Force simulation upon data changes.",
      "name": "restart", "value": false,
      "on": [
        {"events": {"signal": "fix"}, "update": "fix && fix.length"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "node-data",
      "url": "data/miserables.json",
      "format": {"type": "json", "property": "nodes"}
    },
    {
      "name": "link-data",
      "url": "data/miserables.json",
      "format": {"type": "json", "property": "links"}
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "node-data", "field": "group"},
      "range": {"scheme": "category20c"}
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "type": "symbol",
      "zindex": 1,

      "from": {"data": "node-data"},
      "on": [
        {
          "trigger": "fix",
          "modify": "node",
          "values": "fix === true ? {fx: node.x, fy: node.y} : {fx: fix[0], fy: fix[1]}"
        },
        {
          "trigger": "!fix",
          "modify": "node", "values": "{fx: null, fy: null}"
        }
      ],

      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "group"},
          "stroke": {"value": "white"}
        },
        "update": {
          "size": {"signal": "2 * nodeRadius * nodeRadius"},
          "cursor": {"value": "pointer"}
        }
      },

      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "force",
          "iterations": 300,
          "restart": {"signal": "restart"},
          "static": {"signal": "static"},
          "signal": "force",
          "forces": [
            {"force": "center", "x": {"signal": "cx"}, "y": {"signal": "cy"}},
            {"force": "collide", "radius": {"signal": "nodeRadius"}},
            {"force": "nbody", "strength": {"signal": "nodeCharge"}},
            {"force": "link", "links": "link-data", "distance": {"signal": "linkDistance"}}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "zIndex": 2,
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 15},
          "fontWeight": {"value": "bold"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"},
          "text": {"field": "datum.name"}
        },
        "update": {"dx": {"field": "x"}, "dy": {"field": "y"}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "link-data"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#ccc"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "require": {"signal": "force"},
          "shape": "line",
          "sourceX": "datum.source.x", "sourceY": "datum.source.y",
          "targetX": "datum.target.x", "targetY": "datum.target.y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).